# Library install with success in TwinCAT but not updated in my project

Tags: reference, twincat

I'm using my own library in TwinCAT. So in my solution in VS, I have 2 project, one for my PLC the other one for my library. Like that if I have to change something in the library I can do it directly. Then I click on my project "save as a library and install".

Usually after the installation is done, I see that in my PLC Project, under References, my library is updating (clock symbol and the right version appears). It is correctly set to "Set to always new version".

But now I don't know why, it doesn't update the library at all.
In my Twincat/Managed Librarie / ... it does actually update the library but not in my PLC project.
I verified the thing directly in my folders in the PLC project (under _Library) and it doesn't updated.

Do you have any idea how to "restore" this functionnality ?

I'm using TwinCAT v3.1.4024.47

Thank's

I tried to :

- delete the library in the references and add again to force the update.
- manually move the new version library in the _Library of the PLC project
- change the version number of the new library to a highest number also in release mode
- reboot VS, take an older version of the project
- read the beckhoff documentation